# How do I freeze group headers in ListView

Tags: wpf, listview

We have a requirement where ListView group headers need to be freezed while scrolling. I am new to WPF and finding very challenging to implement. Need help. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Maybe this [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801102/wpf-scroll-itemcontrol-content-fixed-header) can give you an hint

Comment: Thank you Vic. That solved my purpose. :)